# Trouble with index

Tags: c++, c++11

Write the find function, which takes a fixed integer vector reference and a single value integer and returns the index of the first occurrence of this value in the vector or the length of the vector if no value in it. The function should be adapted for use in the sample program
below. The function uses only the vector header file.

This is what I've done so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int find(const vector<int> &r ,int number)
{
    int i=0;
    int x;
    for(i;i<r.size();++i)
    {
        if(r[i]==number)
        {
            break;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int result = find(vector<int> {3, -1, 7, 12, -5, 7, 10}, 7);
    cout << result << endl; 
}
```

And, I'm stuck, I don't know how to return the index.

Comment: Replace `break;` to `return i;` and `return 0;` to `return r.size()` in the function.

Comment: It's  2 number of index   if I print it in  inside   "if"  statement  , and 7  outisde the statement and that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `return i;` instead of breaking out of the loop
and maybe return -1 instead of 0 if the number is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Return index `i` when found otherwise return 0 after the loop like this:

```
int find( const std::vector<int>& r, const int number )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i )
    {
        if ( r[i] == number )
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `x` is unused in `find` function.

Comment: Yea sorry , forgot to  delete the   "int x" line

Comment: it is not necessary to use a reference

Comment: @bruno: Right. `int` is pretty trivial for that.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: My bad. Corrected. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Oh, missed the index part while writing that. Updated. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

You should return **i** from your function

Comment: but when I do it  , it shows  the number of iteration  and not the number of index  I want

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25747015)

Comment: @SurajKumar, it is the actual answer to the question. Theooc, number of iterations happens to be the index.